# Conditional formatting based on number of parameters

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook which creates sheets from a summary sheet. I left out the code which creates the sheets as that works as intended.

I am trying to implement conditional formatting rules.
The formatting is made so that it takes the number of part codes as a parameter from the summary sheet to decide which format to produce since more part codes fiddles with the column orientation. As such, in my sub that produces conditional formatting, I segregate by part code so that I can determine which column to format.

Image one is the format for three part codes.
[image]

Image two is the format for two part codes.
[image]

Image three is the format for one part code.
[image]

```vb
Sub ConditionalFormatting(ByVal numberOfPartCodes As Integer)
'Inputs conditional formatting
'Hot Key: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'RUN AFTER INPUTTING VALUES
Dim measuredColumn As Range
Dim partCodeColumn As Range
Dim diaryDateColumn As Range
Dim initialsColumn As Range
Dim reviewedByColumn As Range
Dim rangeUsed As String
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1
'Unused from past attempts at implementation
'Dim indexNumber As Integer
'indexNumber = 9
'Dim rng As Range
'Different ranges to format depending on number of part codes so
'split into different conditionals.
If numberOfPartCodes = 1 Then
'set values to each of the column ranges between the start row and the last row used.
    rangeUsed = "J9:J" & lastRow
    Set measuredColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
    rangeUsed = "L9:L" & lastRow
    Set diaryDateColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
    rangeUsed = "M9:M" & lastRow
    Set initialsColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
    rangeUsed = "N9:N" & lastRow
    Set reviewedByColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
'Apply rule that if the measured column has no value it is highlighted yellow (WORKING).    
    measuredColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
            Formula1:="=0"
    measuredColumn.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
'Apply rule that if the side columns contain no text and the measured column has a value the 
'columns are highlighted yellow. 
    diaryDateColumn.AddRule diaryDateColumn, "=AND(L9="""", J9>0)", vbYellow
    initialsColumn.AddRule initialsColumn, "=AND(M9="""", J9>0)", vbYellow
    reviewedByColumn.AddRule reviewedByColumn, "=AND(N9="""", J9>0)", vbYellow
Else
    If numberOfPartCodes = 2 Then
    'set values to each of the column ranges between the start row and the last row used.
        rangeUsed = "K9:K" & lastRow
        Set measuredColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
        rangeUsed = "N9:N" & lastRow
        Set diaryDateColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
        rangeUsed = "O9:O" & lastRow
        Set initialsColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
        rangeUsed = "P9:P" & lastRow
        Set reviewedByColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
    'Apply rule that if the measured column has no value it is highlighted yellow (WORKING).        
        measuredColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
                Formula1:="=0"
        measuredColumn.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
    'Apply rule that if the side columns contain no text and the measured column has a value 
    'the columns are highlighted yellow.
        diaryDateColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlExpression, _
                Formula1:="$K$9>0"
        diaryDateColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
                Formula1:="="""
        measuredColumn.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        measuredColumn.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        initialsColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlExpression, _
                Formula1:="$K9>0"
        initialsColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
                Formula1:="="""
        measuredColumn.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        measuredColumn.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        reviewedByColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlGreater, _
                Formula1:="K9>0"
        reviewedByColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, Operator:=xlEqual, _
                Formula1:="="""
        measuredColumn.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
        measuredColumn.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

I included in my code two attempts at formatting the cells. The intended conditions I want to pass are that the measured column is highlighted when empty and that the diary date, initials, and reviewed by columns are highlighted when (1) the measured column is not empty and (2) they are empty. The measured column conditions work as intended because I am able to use a rule which only uses that column.

My issue is with the other three columns. I tried to implement several methods, included in code.
The first method is used in the first conditional. This is a syntax that I found in another SO post, but it gets skipped by the compiler when I run the program.
The second included implementation is the expanded form of the first implementation. I tried switching the operators to debug, but nothing seemed to change the outcome. This implementation also gets skipped by the compiler.
Another implementation I attempted was with Call statements. This worked, and I was able to format the sheet, however, this would be too many steps for the users to have the additional button to press after data input.

One of the issues I ran into was that I could assign rules based off of a single range, but I could not then call that rule with another range. An example of this is included in the second half of the code attached where I attempt to apply the created rule to a different column. This compiles but does not run.

---

I have updated my logic to follow a single formula, but it still gets skipped by the compiler. Is there a reason for this?

```vb
diaryDateColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
  Operator:=xlExpression, _
  Formula1:="=AND(L9="""", J9>0)"
diaryDateColumn.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

---

The problem should be found by debugging once I fix the sheet creating sub and reworking it to avoid calling an error handler.

---

I debugged and corrected a couple of errors. However, when I run the statement below, I receive the error

> "Run time error: 449" "Argument not optional".

My guess is it has to do with the formula or the type/operator of the FormatConditions.

```vb
diaryDateColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, _
  Operator:=xlExpression, _
  Formula1:=" =AND($L9="",$J9>0)"
```

Comment: There is no `Range.AddRule` method in VBA so it's not surprising that doesn't work. It is surprising that it compiles though.

Comment: Does the Range.FormatConditions.Add exist as a method in VBA?

Comment: Yes, it does. That part should work.

Comment: If it should be working could the issue be in how the conditions are set? As they are currently set do both apply at the same time or are they independent of each other?

Comment: They will apply in order. It looks like you should be using a formula to check both your criteria at once.

Comment: When I apply the color to the FormatCondition is that intended to be called by the same range or can I apply a different range to it?

Comment: FormatConditions are range specific so I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: In the first segment of my code I created the conditions using one range then called the color of the condition with a different range. If they are range specific that should not work then. However, the code is still skipped when the ranges match.

Comment: There's no way your code should run without error currently as it's honestly a bit of a mess. Do you have an error handler (or On Error Resume Next) in the calling code?

Comment: Yes. I have On Error Resume Next in the source code. It is present because I initialize the created sheet by first checking if it exists. Is there a way I can isolate this so that the error handler does not interact with my conditional formatting sub? My first thought process is to create a function that returns boolean depending on whether the sheet exists or not, but I do not know if error handlers are active outside of the function they are called in.

Comment: No they are not. You should always limit the scope of OERN by resetting to a real error handler or at least using `On Error Goto 0` as soon as practical.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the Operator parameter within the FormatConditions method to declare type instead of the Type parameter. After changing these values, the code works as intended. Thanks for the help!

```
Sub ConditionalFormatting(ByVal numberOfPartCodes As Integer)
'Inputs conditional formatting
'Hot Key: Ctrl+Shift+Q
'RUN AFTER INPUTTING VALUES
Dim measuredColumn As Range
Dim partCodeColumn As Range
Dim diaryDateColumn As Range
Dim initialsColumn As Range
Dim reviewedByColumn As Range
Dim rangeUsed As String
Dim lastRow As Integer
lastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1

'Unused from past attempts at implementation

'Dim indexNumber As Integer
'indexNumber = 9
'Dim rng As Range

'Different ranges to format depending on number of part codes so
'split into different conditionals.

If numberOfPartCodes = 1 Then

'set values to each of the column ranges between the start row and the 
last row used.

    rangeUsed = "J9:J" & lastRow
    Set measuredColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
    rangeUsed = "L9:L" & lastRow
    Set diaryDateColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
    rangeUsed = "M9:M" & lastRow
    Set initialsColumn = Range(rangeUsed)
    rangeUsed = "N9:N" & lastRow
    Set reviewedByColumn = Range(rangeUsed)

'Apply rule that if the measured column has no value it is highlighted 
yellow (WORKING).

    measuredColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlCellValue, 
Operator:=xlEqual, _
            Formula1:="=0"
    measuredColumn.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow

'Apply rule that if the side columns contain no text and the measured 
column has a value the columns are highlighted yellow.

    diaryDateColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
            Formula1:="=AND(L9="""", J9>0)"
    diaryDateColumn.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow

    initialsColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
            Formula1:="=AND(M9="""", J9>0)"
    initialsColumn.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow

    reviewedByColumn.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
            Formula1:="=AND(N9="""", J9>0)"
    reviewedByColumn.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbYellow
```